# Is there a way to show my GitHub commits for a project on my website?

Tags: github

I would like to show the number of GitHub commits I have made to a repository on my website.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

GitHub repositories have an Atom feed for every branch:

```
https://github.com/:user/:repo/commits/:branch.atom
```

For example, https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commits/master.atom.

---

The total commit count can be retrieved from [GitHub Statistics API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/statistics/). Note that this information is computed on demand and counting commits takes some time. If you get an empty response like `{ }`, that means you should retry after a few seconds.

Comment: What I really wanted was a way to show the number of commits made for a project.  I don't really need the whole detail, although that could still be useful.  It seems the number is not there, just a list of commits and their details.

Comment: Why didn't you just ask for that, then?

Comment: I guess I didn't realise I was asking the wrong question, I have amended.

Comment: In fact, using the feed I may well be able to count them using PHP, but if a way already exists then I would prefer to use that.